# Distinct values of Column A summing its respective values at Column B at Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with some values of contracts like this:

| # Contract | Value of contract |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | $ 100 |
| 002 | $200 |
| 001 | $100 |
| 002 | $ 200 |
| 001 | $ 100 |

I want to select the distinct values of column #Contract and sum its values, with this result:

| # Contract | Value of contract |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | $ 100 |
| 002 | $200 |

If possible, it will be also better have only the result of the sum ($ 300). How can I do this at power bi?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Measure =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table', 
        'Table'[# Contract],
        'Table'[Value of contract]
    ),
    [Value of contract]
)
```